# Do WINGS activities count when your medical is expired?

Tags: faa

I flew with a flight instructor a few months ago, and he gave me a WINGS credit for the flight.  My medical was expired at the time.  I have since renewed my medical and it's current now, and I'm going to do more flights to get two more WINGS credits to count as a flight review.  The WINGS programs states that pilots must have a medical certificate to participate in the program.  Do I have to do that one WINGS activity over again since my medical was expired at the time I did it?  I have already been given credit for it on the WINGS website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [AC 61-91J](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentid/903551) (emphasis mine):

> All pilots (including student pilots) holding an FAA-issued pilot
> certificate and any *required* medical certificate may participate in the WINGS Program.

It doesn't say "any medical certificate," it says "any *required* medical certificate." My reading of this is that certain tasks require a medical certificate, and you can't participate in those tasks without one. For instance, you would need a medical certificate for a task that requires soloing but not one that involves receiving dual training or going to a seminar.

The [FAQ](https://www.faasafety.gov/onlinehelp/faq.aspx) reinforces this, with more clear wording: (emphasis mine)

> Q. Who can participate in WINGS?
>
> All pilots holding a U.S. pilot certificate and a current medical certificate, *when required*, including student pilots, may participate in the WINGS Program and receive a flight review date extension upon completion of a Phase. However, we encourage participation even if you don't hold a current certificate. Retired, foreign and student pilots can still benefit from the safety training offered on nFAASafety.gov and through the WINGS program; however the flight review date extension you may receive by completing a Phase of WINGS will not be valid without a current certificate.

Comment: Ah yes, this sounds right.  So the previous activity does count.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer @chris posted, the information below is from the ["Wings Pilot Proficiency Users Guide," dated January 24, 2011](https://www.faasafety.gov/files/events/GL/GL05/2010/GL0533897/Wings_Manual-20110125-Draft4.pdf) :

**Paragraph 1.2 Who Can Participate**: (pertinent portion)

> All pilots holding a U.S. pilot certificate (**and a current medical certificate if your instructor cannot act as PIC**) may participate in the WINGS Program. Requests to participate in flight portions of the program should be made to certificated or authorized flight and ground instructors, flight schools, and FAASTeam Members participating in the program.

*(emphasis is mine)*